# Write a short C++ program that outputs all possible strings formed by using each of the characters ’a’, ’b’, ’c’, ’d’, ’e’, and ’f’ exactly once

Tags: c++

I came across this question and I am not able to solve it. All I could code was for small strings like **ab,ac,ad,ae,af** and such. But not for the longer strings like **abc,abcd,etc**. It would be really nice if someone could direct me towards some kind of solution. I would prefer **without recursion** but if not then **recursion** is also fine.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<string> make_string(vector<char>vec, char ch)
{
    int i=0;
    vec.erase(remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ch), vec.end());
    int size = vec.size();
    vector<string>all_strings;
    string answer="";

    for(i=0;i<size;i++) //here is the "meat". I could add a few more for loops for longer strings
                        // But I think that would just get messy.
    {
        answer= answer+ch+vec[i];
        all_strings.push_back(answer);
        answer="";
    }
    return all_strings;
}

void print_vector(vector<string>vec)    
{
    int i=0;
    int size = vec.size();
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout<<vec[i]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"--------------------------";
    cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<char>vec;
    vec.push_back('a');
    vec.push_back('b');
    vec.push_back('c');
    vec.push_back('d');
    vec.push_back('e');
    vec.push_back('f');
    int i=0;
    vector<string>my_strings;

    int size=vec.size();

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        my_strings=make_string(vec,vec[i]);
        print_vector(my_strings);
        my_strings.clear();
    }



    return 0;   

}
```

Comment: For "each character exactly once" you can use std::next_permutation in the algorithm header. For "atmost once", you will have to try something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for a permutation algorithm. Please take a look at this post on wordaligned.org, which describes an iterative solution to the problem:

[Next permutation](http://wordaligned.org/articles/next-permutation)

The author's code is very simple and makes use of the standard library:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    char xs[] = "abcdef"; // <-- modified to fit the question.
    do
    {
        std::puts(xs);
    }
    while (std::next_permutation(xs, xs + sizeof(xs) - 1));
    return 0;
}
```

If you read further, there is a discussion on the implementation of `next_permutation` and a breakdown of how it works.